# MySQL adding columns together in SELECT statement (with aliases)

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my select statement.  Basically I'm trying to total all of my columns together for a total.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, 
MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['email'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as exactEmailScore,
MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['firstName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as firstNameScore,
MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['lastName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as lastNameScore, 
MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['organizationName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as orgScore 
FROM contacts_search;
```

What I would like to add to my select is:

```
(exactEmailScore + firstNameScore + lastNameScore + orgScore) as total
```

But what is receive is: Unknown column 'exactEmailScore' in 'field list'.

I bumped around but couldn't find anything concrete.  Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if this is not the same in MySQL as it is in TSQL/SQL Server.

If you treat your current results as a set and wrap in parentheses, you can do another select to get your results plus the new calculated value.

```
Select exactEmailScore, firstNameScore, lastNameScore, orgScore,
       CONCAT(exactEmailScore, firstNameScore, lastNameScore, orgScore) as total
 From
(SELECT DISTINCT *, 
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['email'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as exactEmailScore,
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['firstName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as firstNameScore,
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['lastName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as lastNameScore, 
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['organizationName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as orgScore 
FROM contacts_search
) results
```

Comment: change the `+` to `,` and add `CONCAT()` to it.. thats how you do it in MySQL [**Docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell.  Updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with copy-paste?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, 
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['email'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as exactEmailScore,
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['firstName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as firstNameScore,
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['lastName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as lastNameScore, 
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['organizationName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as orgScore,
    MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['email'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +
        MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['firstName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +
        MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['lastName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) +  
        MATCH (crm_contacts_search.data) AGAINST ( '" . $keywords['organizationName'] ."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as total
FROM contacts_search;
```

MySQL will evaluate indentical MATCH .... AGAINST only once